# Browser window open the URL then suddenly closes in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

The problem is that as the browser window open the Facebook page I expect it to click on the Create New Account .
The XPATH for Create New Account that I used is

```
//a[text()='Create New Account']
```

but it open's facebook.com then suddenly closes although I have other scripts working properly.

The complete Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://facebook.com")

link_locator = '//a[text()="Create New Account"]'
create_account = Wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, link_locator))).click()
```

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: no exceptions. just closes the session .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser has been closed immediately, coz there was just command click, driver made it and due to nothing next, closed the driver.

Try to add time.sleep(10) at the end, and you will see that signup pop appeared:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://facebook.com")

link_locator = '//a[text()="Create New Account"]'
create_account = Wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, link_locator))).click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```